# Summing depth data (consecutive rows) in R

Tags: r, depth, microsoft-r

How is it possible with to sum up consecutive depth data with R?
For instance:

```
a <- data.frame(label = as.factor(c("Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Wood","Wood","Wood","Wood","Wood","Air","Air","Air","Air","Stone","Stone","Stone","Stone","Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Wood","Wood")), 
                depth = as.numeric(c(1,2,3,-1,4,5,4,5,4,6,8,9,8,9,10,9,10,11,10,11,12,10,12,13,14,14)))
```

The given output should be something like:

```
Label Depth
Air    7
Wood   3
Stone  1
```

First the removal of negative values is done with `cummax()`, because depth can only increase in this special case. Hence:

```
   label depth
1    Air     1
2    Air     2
3    Air     3
4    Air     3
5    Air     4
6    Air     5
7   Wood     5
8   Wood     5
9   Wood     5
10  Wood     6
11  Wood     8
12   Air     9
13   Air     9
14   Air     9
15   Air    10
16 Stone    10
17 Stone    10
18 Stone    11
19 Stone    11
20   Air    11
21   Air    12
22   Air    12
23   Air    12
24   Air    13
25  Wood    14
26  Wood    14
```

Now by max-min the increase in depth for every consecutive row you would get: **(the question is how to do this step)**

```
   label depth
1   Air     4
2   Wood    3
3   Air     1
4   Stone   1
5   Air     2
5   Wood    0
```

And finally summing up those max-min values the output is the one presented above.

**Steps tried to achieve the output:**

The first obvious solution would be for instance for Air:

```
diff(cummax(a[a$label=="Air",]$depth))
```

This solution gets rid of the negative data, which is necessary due to an expected constant increase in depth.
The problem is the output also takes into account the big steps in between each consecutive subset. Hence, the sum for Air would be 12 instead of 7.

```
 [1] 1 1 0 1 1 4 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Even worse would be a solution with aggreagte, e.g.:

```
aggregate(depth~label, a, FUN=function(x){sum(x>0)})
```

Note: solutions with filtering big jumps is not what i'm looking for. Sure you could hard code a limit for instance <2 for the example of Air once again:

```
sum(diff(cummax(a[a$label=="Air",]$depth))[diff(cummax(a[a$label=="Air",]$depth))<2])
```

Gives you almost the right result but does not work as it is expected here. I'm pretty sure there is already a function for what I'm looking for because it is not a uncommon problem for many different tasks.

I guess taking the minimum and maximum value of each set of consecutive rows per material and summing those up would be one possible solution, but I'm not sure how to apply a function to only the consecutive subsets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::rleid` to quickly group by run, or reconstruct it with `rle` if you really like. After that, aggregating is fairly easy in any grammar. In dplyr,

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(label = c("Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Wood","Wood","Wood","Wood","Wood","Air","Air","Air","Air","Stone","Stone","Stone","Stone","Air","Air","Air","Air","Air","Wood","Wood"), 
                depth = c(1,2,3,-1,4,5,4,5,4,6,8,9,8,9,10,9,10,11,10,11,12,10,12,13,14,14))

a2 <- a %>% 
    # filter to rows where previous value is lower, equal, or NA
    filter(depth >= lag(depth) | is.na(lag(depth))) %>% 
    # group by label and its run
    group_by(label, run = data.table::rleid(label)) %>% 
    summarise(depth = max(depth) - min(depth))    # aggregate

a2 %>% arrange(run)    # sort to make it pretty
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   label [3]
#>    label   run depth
#>   <fctr> <int> <dbl>
#> 1    Air     1     4
#> 2   Wood     2     3
#> 3    Air     3     1
#> 4  Stone     4     1
#> 5    Air     5     2
#> 6   Wood     6     0

a3 <- a2 %>% summarise(depth = sum(depth))    # a2 is still grouped, so aggregate more

a3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    label depth
#>   <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1    Air     7
#> 2  Stone     1
#> 3   Wood     3
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R method using `aggregate` is

```
aggregate(cbind(val=cummax(a$depth)),
          list(label=a$label, ID=c(0, cumsum(diff(as.integer(a$label)) != 0))),
          function(x) diff(range(x)))
```

The first argument to aggregate calculates the cumulative maximum as the OP does above for the input vector, the use of `cbind` provide for the final output of the calculated vector. The second argument is the grouping argument. This uses a different method than `rle`, which calculates the cumulative sum of the differences. Finally, the third argument provides the function which calculates the desired output by taking a difference of the range for each group.

This returns

```
  label ID val
1   Air  0   4
2  Wood  1   3
3   Air  2   1
4 Stone  3   1
5   Air  4   2
6  Wood  5   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` way (borrowing in part from @alistaire):

```
setDT(a)
a[, depth := cummax(depth)]
depth_gain <- a[,
  list(
    depth = max(depth) - depth[1],  # Only need the starting and max values
    label = label[1]
  ),
  by = rleidv(label)
]
result <- depth_gain[, list(depth = sum(depth)), by = label]
```